# Twitter API 1.1 get tweets from multiple users

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter

I know this have been asked several times. But none of the answers are helping me. I'm using the TwitterAPIExchange library and I'm using cakephp. Here is a bit of my code

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=from:desertwinds09+OR+from:teffy0402&count=5';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
```

And thats it. But when I run it this is what I get:

```
{"statuses":[],"search_metadata":{"completed_in":0.005,"max_id":385960905676427264,"max_id_str":"385960905676427264","query":"from%3Adesertwinds09%2BOR%2Bfrom%3Ateffy0402","refresh_url":"?since_id=385960905676427264&q=from%3Adesertwinds09%2BOR%2Bfrom%3Ateffy0402&include_entities=1","count":5,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}}
```

And that just doesn't make sense. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is twofold.

Firstly, the user `teffy0402` has their tweets protected. You can't access the tweets of someone with a protected account, *unless you are the authenticating user who owns that account*.

Try another user instead:

```
$getfield = '?q=from:desertwinds09+OR+from:nonprotectedaccount&count=5';
```

Secondly, the user `desertwinds09` **doesn't have any tweets** since the id: `386093442759417856`.

You need to get the two individual parts working first before trying them together with an OR.